# How do I set up a flag to allow the integer to be only saved once in my label in Swift?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, nsuserdefaults, flags

I have a game with 10 levels and each level has an orb that a user can collect. When the user collects the orb the first time it should add +1 to the label and save using NSUserDefaults. That works fine but when I play the same level and I collect the orb again it shouldnt add another +1 to the label. I only need to add +1 for each orb in each of the levels. So that would be a total of 10 orbs saved in the label if the user collects all the orbs. What am I doing wrong?

```
class LevelOne: SKScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate {
var didCollectOrb = true


override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
if didCollectOrb == true {

    UserDefaults().set(UserDefaults().integer(forKey: "saveOrbs")+0, forKey:"saveOrbs")
    print("will add nothing to label")
}
}

    func didBegin(_ contact:SKPhysicsContact){

    var firstBody: SKPhysicsBody
    var secondBody: SKPhysicsBody

    // 2. Assign the two physics bodies so that the one with the lower category is always stored in firstBody

    if contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask < contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask {
        firstBody = contact.bodyA
        secondBody = contact.bodyB
    } else {
        firstBody = contact.bodyB
        secondBody = contact.bodyA
    }


if firstBody.categoryBitMask == HeroCategory && secondBody.categoryBitMask == OrbCategory {

    //saves orbs
    if didCollectOrb {
    UserDefaults().set(UserDefaults().integer(forKey: "saveOrbs")+1, forKey:"saveOrbs")
    print("will add +1 to label")

    }

  }
}

}
```

Comment: Where are you setting the `text` value of the label?

Comment: orbLabel.text = UserDefaults().integer(forKey: "saveOrbs").description

Comment: Misread your comment I have the label in my GameScene.swift file in the didMoveToView.

Answer (score 0):

Tracking the `Int` value in `UserDefaults` is probably not the best way since there is no innate duplication prevention. If a person completes level 1 10 times, then they have collected 10 orbs according to that `UserDefaults` value. Perhaps you would prefer a binary or boolean storing method. For example, an easy way to implement it would be either a dictionary or array, e.g.:

```
let levels = [false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false] //10 values for 10 levels

func completeLevel(level: Int) { //takes a level from 1-10
    self.levels[level - 1] = true
}
```

Then completing a level multiple times:

```
completeLevel(level: 1)
completeLevel(level: 1)
completeLevel(level: 1)
completeLevel(level: 1)
completeLevel(level: 1)
```

Will still only show `true` at that level index. So getting the "total number of collected orbs" is something like:

```
func getOrbs() -> Int {
    var orbs = 0
    self.levels.forEach { orbs += $0 ? 1 : 0 }
    return orbs
}
```

I wouldn't recommend just copying and pasting this since this isn't a great implementation. Just try to understand how this works so that you can find a better way of storing the score while preventing unwanted duplication of orb counts.